# How can I add an editable child component in another component using React in AEM?

Tags: reactjs, single-page-application, aem, aem-6, aem-touch-ui

The requirement is to add a child component which is editable on its own within another component.

If I just include the component in React, it is static(No dialog available & not editable). Tried referring to this but the same issue here as well - https://experienceleague.adobe.com/docs/experience-manager-learn/getting-started-with-aem-headless/spa-editor/how-to/react-core-components-v2.html?lang=en

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.